# Access to a data from a response AJAX called in a template file php

Tags: ajax, pagination, get-template-part

I use an ajax called to get all posts of a custom post type and other criteria.

I would like to get the response of my ajax called and use it in a template php file. So my question is : how can I pass the data from response ajax to template php file ?

Here my code js  :

```js
function getPlayers($post_type) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {
          action: display_players_list,
          post_type: $post_type.data('type'),
      },

      success: function(data){

          // would like to pass the data to my template php file


        },
  });
}
```

This is my function display_players_list with a piece of code (here in comments) where I try to do this.

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_display_players_list', 'display_players_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_display_players_list', 'display_players_list');
function display_players_list(){

    $get_current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];

    // players
    $players = get_players($post_type);
    if ( $players->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $players->the_post();
        $current_post = get_post();
        $array_data[] = $current_post;
      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }

/*
$args = [
  'total_players' => $players->found_posts,
  'total_pages' => $players->max_num_pages,
];

?><section><?php
get_template_part('template/players-list', null, $args);
?></section><?php
exit();
*/
    wp_send_json($array_data);
}
```

The get_players function is a simple WP_QUERY.

Thanks for help

Comment: You've commented out the correct solution. You need to return the template output as the AJAX response. Is there a reason you commented it out?

Comment: Yes because It does not work ! When I dump $args in my template part, I have an error because args is undefined...

Comment: `$array_data` is being used at the end but it doesn't exist and isn't mentioned or defined beforehand, there are syntax errors in your javascript code, as well as other errors. You call `get_players($post_type);` but where is `$post_type` coming from? Did you mean to use `documents_type` instead? These should all be generating PHP warnings and PHP notices in your error log, you shouldn't ignore warnings and notices as they indicate bugs in the code and silent failures

Comment: Also is there a particular reason you're using the legacy admin ajax API for AJAX instead of the modern REST API?

Comment: Sorry I forgot lines of codes. So I edit my first message.